# jquery ui slider respond to scroll

Tags: slider, jquery

I have a vertical slider built using the jquery ui slider plugin.

I would like to be able to scroll the slider up and down with the mouse wheel when the mouse is over the slider.

Since the slider is not a scrollable object it does not respond to the `.scroll` method.

I have found a workaround by checking if the mouse is over the slider when the window scrolls. By using this method I have two problems:

1- Even though I use the `event.preventDefault()` the window still scrolls...

2- If the window is scrolled all the way up, the slider can no longer scroll up even if it's not at the first position.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
    if (mouseSlider) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Doesn't stop window from scrolling
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            $('#next-day').click();
        } else {
            $('#prev-day').click();
        }
        lastScrollTop = st;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4xCyk/1/

Why is the `event.preventDefault()` functionning correctly ? Is there a way to enable scrolling even if the scrollbar is a the top ?

Or is there a much easier way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this using a Jquery plugin:
https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

```
$('#slider').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0)
        $('#prev-day').click();
    else
        $('#next-day').click();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer "1- Even though I use the event.preventDefault() the window still scrolls..."

because you declared `mouseSlider` with `var mouseSlider` which creates a local variable not a global one to use in different function

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/4xCyk/9/

Comment: If `mouseSlider` was not accessible from within the scroll function the slider would never move. With or without the `var` it works the exact same way. The fiddle in your example has the same outcome as mine...